# Why the add-on oAuth scope and oAuth client shows 'Not granted' in admin console

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

Why are the oAuth scope (especially ' https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds ') and oAuth client display "Not granted" in the admin console(path: Apps > Admin install Google Workspace Marketplace apps > my Addon)

How can I give authorization? And would it affect my normal use

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would need to double check the Add-on you have created if it meets the prerequisites for OAuth 2.0 as stated here in this [reference article.](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow)

You can also check out this [article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) for OAuth 2.0 Client ID if the requested access token is still active.